# I am getting System.Collections.Generic.List`1[ConsoleApp1.Program.Employee] instead of the list's contents? c#

Tags: c#, list, dictionary

```
class Employee
      {
         public string Name{get;set;}
         public int Age{get;set;}
         public int ID{get;set;}
      }

      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
        List<Employee> EmployeeList = new();

        EmployeeList.Add(new Employee() { Name = "Luís", Age = 19, ID = 1 });
        EmployeeList.Add(new Employee() { Name = "Sofia", Age = 25, ID = 2 });
        EmployeeList.Add(new Employee() { Name = "Gilberto", Age = 57, ID = 3 });
        EmployeeList.Add(new Employee() { Name = "Manuel", Age = 25, ID = 4 });
        EmployeeList.Add(new Employee() { Name = "Sofia", Age = 25, ID = 2 });


        var EmployeeDic = EmployeeList.GroupBy(i => i.Age).ToDictionary(gdc => gdc.Key, gdc => gdc.ToList());
        
        foreach (var emp in EmployeeDic)
        {
                Console.WriteLine("" + emp.Key + emp.Value);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();}
```

I have done a lot of research and I can't get the value, just the key that is the age of the employees. What can I try next?

Comment: `emp.Value` is a `List<Employee>`, and if you do `new List<Employee>().ToString()`, you'll get the output you saw. Perhaps you want to loop through each element in `emp.Value` (which is an `Employee`), and print it out?

Comment: _"and i can't get the value"_ What value are you expecting to receive based on your code? `EmployeeDic` is a dictionary. What is the type of the dictionary key? Therefore, what type should `emp.Key` contain? What is the type of the dictionary value? Therefore, what type should `emp.Value` contain?

Comment: the key of the dictionary will be the age because of the groupby and thats working, emp.value is containing a list and i cant find a way to loop emp.value to get for example the name of the employees.

Comment: @tommy: So you're aware that `emp.Value` is a `List<Employee>`. How do you loop through a list? I'm asking this as a question because there's significantly more educational value to find the answer yourself. (1) Look up how to iterate through a list (2) `emp.Value` is a list, so you can iterate through it (3) handle each element (`Employee`) of the list the way you want it to be handled.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```cs
var EmployeeDic = EmployeeList.GroupBy(i => i.Age).ToDictionary(gdc => gdc.Key, gdc => gdc.ToList());
```

That line creates `list`s of employees by age. Specifically a list of employees aged 19, then another list of employees aged 25, then finally a list of employees aged 57.

```cs
foreach (var emp in EmployeeDic)
```

That line loops through the lists.

```cs
Console.WriteLine("" + emp.Key + emp.Value);
```

That line then outputs information about the list. This is not the intended behaviour of the code, so consequently the output is not helpful.

---

The solution is to keep the code which loops around the lists, but then have another loop within that, which loops through each employee within that list.

Like so: (replace your loop with this)

```cs
foreach (var empList in EmployeeDic)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Age {0}", empList.Key);
    foreach (var emp in empList.Value)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\t{0} has an ID of {1}", emp.Name, emp.ID);
    }
}
```

The output of that is:

[image]